# How to get the specific users details from the database in the dashboard after login in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am having a registration,login and a dashboard page the registration form consists of username,email,password,goal,design,furniture,room so in these the username,email will be stored in custom user model and the remaining details will be stored in the user_requirement table and the login page consists of username and password which will be authenticated and get to the dashboard page now In dashboard page I am trying to display the goal,design,furniture,room details which the particular user given during registration
My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages, auth
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from contacts.models import Contact
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages,auth
from account.forms import UserForm
from account.forms import UserRequirementForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login


def register(request):
  return render(request, 'account/register.html',);
def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # if there is a post request in the form
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST) #first of all it is a user_form will be posted details present in the user_form
        user_requirement_form = UserRequirementForm(data=request.POST)# after posting the details of the user_form post the details
        if user_form.is_valid() and user_requirement_form.is_valid():
         # if user_form & user_requirement form is valid

         User = user_form.save()#if form is valid save
         User.set_password(request.POST['password'])
         User.save()
         user_requirement = user_requirement_form.save(commit=False)
         # Set user
         user_requirement.user = User
         user_requirement.save()
         user_requirement_form.save_m2m()
         messages.success(request,('Project saved successfully'))
         return render(request,'account/home1.html')
        else:
          messages.warning(request, 'Please correct the errors above')
    else:  
        user_form = UserForm()
        user_requirement_form = UserRequirementForm()
    return render(request,'account/register.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'requirements_form': user_requirement_form})

def login(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
      if user.is_active:
        auth.login(request, user)
        messages.success(request, 'You are now logged in')
        return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
      messages.error(request,'Invalid')
      return redirect('login')
  else:
    return render(request, 'account/login.html')

def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html',);
```

dashboard.html:

```
<details>
  <summary class="summary ml-4">User Details</summary>
  <p class="p1 ml-4">The contents that are selected by the user</p>
  <p class="p2 ml-4">All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.</p>
</details>

<p class="p3 ml-4 mt-4"><b>Room:<br></b>{{user.room}}</p>
<p class="p4 ml-4"><b>GOAL:</b><br>{{user.goal}}</p>
<p class="p5 ml-4"><b>FURNITURE:</b><br>{{user.furniture}}</p>
<p class="p6 ml-4"><b>DESIGN:</b><br>{{user.design}}</p>
```

My models.py:

```
class User_Requirement(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(room,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    goal = models.ManyToManyField(goal)
    design = models.ManyToManyField(design)
    furniture = models.ForeignKey(furniture,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

Comment: When A Client Sent Request You Access users infos with `request.user`

Comment: @sina the room and all the other details that were stored in user_requirement table for a particular user should be displayed in dashboard page

Comment: ok you have to render the template engine and pass any user information from backend with your keys;

Comment: yes I tried but for many to many relationship it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.user` will give the currently logged-in user's details.Here you have the `OneToOne` relation with your `User_Requirement` model so you can try like this

```
<p class="p3 ml-4 mt-4"><b>Room:<br></b>{{request.user.user_requirement.room}}</p>
```

**Edit** based on Comment:

Since your goal is a ManyToMany Field you need to iterate it

```
 <p class="p4 ml-4"><b>GOAL:</b>
     {% for goal in request.user.user_requirement.goal.all %}
    <br>{{goal}}</p>

   {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %} #if you want to separate goals with comma

    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: it works fine but there are goals many {{request.user.user_requirement.goal}} when I give like this I am getting account.goal.None can you please help me

Comment: @sssss your goal is None then.

Comment: No @arjun my goal field is manytomany relationship to goals table there are two goals in the table

Comment: there are two goals in the user_requirement table

Comment: could you please help me why they are not coming.

Comment: even the GOAL heading is also not coming @arjun

Comment: yes its there @arjun I had checked see my models.py in my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206049/discussion-between-arjun-and-sssss).